# Can't connect to sql server express through the network using c#

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

I have SQL Server 2016 Express running on a network server. I can access SQL Server on the server and run queries.

On the server:

- tcp/ip enabled, named pipes enabled and tcp ip address IPALL is listening on port 1433, tcp dynamic ports for this ip is blank
- SQL Server Browser is running
- Firewall

  - Inbound Rules port 1433 is open and enabled
  - Outbound Rules port 1433 is open and allow connections
- Server name is: `CLW2016S-1`, SQL Server instance is `SQLEXPRESS`
- The server's IP4 address is 192.168.2.11

This is an internal application and I am connecting as 'sa'. In my project I tried different connect strings, they all generate the same error when I try and create the connection

```
static string connStr = "Data Source=192.168.2.11\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=myzpp;User ID=sa;Password=A$$#@123; ";

static string connStr = "Data Source=\\\\CLW2016S-1\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=myzpp;User ID=sa;Password=A$$#@123; ";

static string connStr = "Data Source=192.168.2.11\\SQLEXPRESS,1433;Initial Catalog=myzpp;User ID=sa;Password=A$$#@123; ";

static string connStr = "Data Source=192.168.2.11\\CLW2016S-1\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=myzpp;User ID=sa;Password=A$$#@123; ";
```

They all generate the same error after this command

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
```

> 'conn.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

It is probably some missing setup for network access on the server but I've been looking for it for 2 days.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: If you're running a named instance of SQL Server rather than a default instance, then port 1434 also needs to be open on both server and client.

Comment: I suggest you try the `PING` and `TELNET` tests shown on this page: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-sql-connectivity-issues/

Comment: @DeanOC sqlexpress is always been a named instance

Comment: Have you **enabled** the remote connections feature (which is **OFF** by default in SQL Server Express)? [Check out this blog post](https://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/) on how to do it

Comment: The only `InvalidOperationException` that `ServerVersion` should throw is if the connection *hasn't been opened yet*. What is the *message* that comes alongside that exception?

Comment: I've opened UDP port 1434 for inbound and outbound. Remote connection was already enabled, The connection error happens when I try and create (before opening). Right now I have our IT guy checking the remote computer, he installed a new update from Microsoft which is causing some network problems and may be the reason for the connection failure. Thank you for all your help, I'll keep this post open until I can retest once the network problems are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all that responded.

The problem was triggered by a Windows Update 18.03 which when combined with our Symantec End Point protection caused some PCs to be "not trusted" members.

Our IT person is working with Symantec to address this issue. He was able with their help to bring the windows 10 pcs back to the fold (it looks like windows 7 was not affected)

Damien you were technically correct, the code that I posted was a few lines prior to opening the connection, but I was still not able to retrieve data.

I am not sure on how to vote for your answer. If anyone could help me with this I'd appreciate.

Paul